# Which crops involve the least collateral harm when grown/harvested?

Tags: commercial-farming, agriculture, subsistence-farming

Some crops can harm animals indirectly while grown/harvested.

Researcher Brian Tomasik has tried to do some rough [estimates](http://reducing-suffering.org/crop-cultivation-and-wild-animals/#A_specific_attempt_at_ranking): for example, legumes appears to inflict less accidental suffering than cereals. Sunflower seeds [may](http://www.democraticunderground.com/discuss/duboard.php?az=view_all&address=294x449) sometimes be protected by poisoning birds. Etc.

What crops generally cause the least accidental harm?? Which ones kill and/or harm the biggest number of animals?